# Java: null of default value of object is better

Tags: java, null, arraylist, default-value

The first case: 
There is a class that has another class as its data member. When this class is instantiated, what we should do with the data member?

- (A) In constructor: this.anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
- (B) left it null, no need to instantiate it.

The second case:
There is a class that has an ArrayList as its data member. When this class is instantiated, what we should do with the ArrayList?

- (A) In constructor: this.bulidingList = new ArrayList< Building >();
- (B) left it null, no need to instantiate it.

The third case:
when we create a method in which its return type is a **collection**, for example

> public **ArrayList< Building >** getBuildingList(){
>       /// Bah Bah Bah.. 
>   }

if there is no Building, we should return the empty ArrayList "**new ArrayList< Building >()**" "or **null**.

Comment: One answer to all your questions is "It varies and depends on how the interface is designed."

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer not using null to avoid potential `NullPointerException`'s. To avoid creating unnecessary objects you could construct a single static instance to return, as long as it's immutable. As for an empty `ArrayList`, you can use `Collections.emptyList()` to do this for you.

In the end it's up to you how you want to define how your API works. Either way you should clearly document it so the caller knows what to expect.

Comment: +1 because an empty Collection is certainly better than null (unless you have a very good reason, as usual)

Answer (score 2):

What are your needs? My general preference is to return null when possible as this avoids creating another object in memory.

Provided that you ensure the documentation clearly states that the method may return null and it is the responsibility of calling code to handle that, I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no concrete answer. It is a case of your API, or, speaking simpler, the expectations of the surrounded code.

Try to think in details about your getBuildingList(). Is it ok to return null? Or null is forbidden and you should return empty list?

Anyway, docuemtn you thoughts in javadoc for the method.

Answer (score 1):

Given the destructive nature of Nulls in Java, I think it's a good practice to return empty collections rather then null collections.

For Objects, you should return "null" if the object has no values set internally.

Answer (score 1):

Is a default-initialized object meaningful, as an empty ArrayList certainly is? Then instantiate it. Don't optimize prematurely.

On the other hand, if a default `AnotherClass` makes no sense, then leave the member as null.

Finally, **if** you run into performance or memory usage problems, consider revising the design.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is best to design your APIs to *avoid* returning a `null` if there is a better alternative.

- For collections, return an empty collection; e.g. `Collections.emptyList()` or `new ArrayList()` ... depending on the API requirements.
- For arrays, return an array of length zero.
- For objects, consider whether it is feasible to use a distinguished instance of the class, or to design the API so that the result can't be `null` in the first place.

If you do need to return `null`, or accept `null` as a method parameter, make sure that the javadoc clearly states that this is a valid result / argument ... and *what it means*.

---

The problem with APIs that use `null` is that developers *forget* about the `null` case and the result is an unexpected `NullPointerException`.  You could say that's not the API designer's fault - the API user should have read the documentation.  But that doesn't really address the issue.  A better approach is to avoid returning the `null` in the first place, especially in cases where there is a simple alternative.

The other point is that a non-null value is generally easier for the caller to deal with.  A `null` typically has to be dealt with as a special case by the calling code.  A non-null value doesn't.  For example, you can iterate over an empty collection or array using a `for` loop, but a `null` has to be tested for explicitly.

Comment: +1 but if you return Collections.emptyList() you need to document that the list is immutable

Comment: @Sean - you have to do that for a non-empty list too.

Comment: obviously, yes. And I'm not telling you, I'm making an addendum for the less experienced :-)

Answer (score 0):

> The third case: when we create a
>   method in which its return type is a
>   collection, for example

```
public ArrayList< Building > getBuildingList(){ /// Bah Bah Bah.. }
```

This is awful, a public member should never return an implementation type. The signature should be:

```
public List< Building > getBuildingList()
```

That way you can (and should) return `Collections.emptyList()` if your data is empty.

Answer (score 0):

> The first case: There is a class that has another class as its data member. When this class is instantiated, what we should do with the data member?
>
> (A) In constructor: this.anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
>
> (B) left it null, no need to instantiate it.

I would prefer (C) In constructor: require a non-null `AnotherClass` parameter.

If you need a default constructor and you always expect the caller to also call `setAnotherClass()` afterwards you could leave it `null` in the constructor and check for null when you actually use the field, otherwise you should probably create a default `AnotherClass` object in the constructor.

> The second case: There is a class that has an ArrayList as its data member. When this class is instantiated, what we should do with the ArrayList?
>
> (A) In constructor: this.bulidingList = new ArrayList< Building >();
>   (B) left it null, no need to instantiate it.

I would always instantiate it, but if the list is read-only I'd declare it this way instead:

```
List<Building> buildingList = Collections.emptyList();
```

> The third case: when we create a method in which its return type is a collection, for example
>
> public ArrayList< Building > getBuildingList(){ /// Bah Bah Bah.. }
>
> if there is no Building, we should return the empty ArrayList "new ArrayList< Building >()" "or null.

I'm not especially proud about it, but I do sometimes return `null` when I want an additional return value, something like `getBuildingsListAndReturnNullIfThereAreNoTenants`. When you just want to say "I haven't found any buildings" it's always better to return an empty list instead.

Sometimes you can do an upfront check and return `Collections.emptyList()` instead of creating a new `ArrayList<Building>` instance, but I wouldn't go out of my way to do it.